# IIS - Able to access local IP but not external IP

Tags: iis, dynamic

I am encountering this problem where I am able to access my IIS Web Application through 192.168.0.15:8090 (Local IP) but not through 92.251.98.7:8090 (External IP).

These are the steps I have taken so far:

1. Set Binding on my project on IIS to accept all requests on Port 8090
2. Set Port Forwarding on my Cisco Router
3. Restart Router / IIS
4. Temporarily Disabled Firewall to debug this problem

Another application is accessible through 92.251.98.7:8080 - I have tried to follow the same steps but I still cannot figure this out.

Did I miss something?

Comment: What model is your Cisco router? Are you trying to access the external IP from inside your network?

Answer (score 1):

If that is your actual IP address (92.251.98.7), I cannot ping it from here.  You may want to use a tool such as [Wormly Remote Ping](https://www.wormly.com/test_remote_ping) to try pinging your public IP address from outside of your network.  If you think you do not have any active firewalls but you cannot ping it, then it is possible that you missed a firewall somewhere and it could be responsible for the other port being blocked.  I would try putting it on port 80 temporarily just to see if that port is being blocked by a firewall as well.  (Sometimes port 80 is permitted by default.)

Once you are sure you are able to ping your own IP address, you can troubleshoot further from there.  Make sure you are doing all of these tests outside of your network.